# Nginx test failed, service not starting

Tags: server, nginx

nginx did not start upon system reboot. tried to manually start it in the terminal. received the following errors. what do they mean, and how do I fix it so that nginx starts?

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-05-18 11:45:39 EDT; 10s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 23664 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 18 11:45:39 jUbuntu systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 18 11:45:39 jUbuntu nginx[23664]: nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
May 18 11:45:39 jUbuntu nginx[23664]: 2018/05/18 11:45:39 [emerg] 23664#23664: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
May 18 11:45:39 jUbuntu nginx[23664]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
May 18 11:45:39 jUbuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 18 11:45:39 jUbuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 11:45:39 jUbuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

In `/var/log/` there wasn't an `nginx` folder.

I added an `nginx` folder to `/var/log/` so that the `/var/log/nginx` folder is present and usable.